# Estimating a "true" value with a noisy number of additive noises

Tags: estimation, modeling, model, small-sample

I want to recover an estimate of the "true" value of a variable from a small set of noisy observations (5–20). I have an *a priori* model describing the physical process that generates the observations, but unfortunately it's a complicated one:

$$x_i = 2k_i X + \sum_{j=1}^{2k_i} n_{ij} \qquad i = 1,\ldots,N$$

where $x_i$ is an observation, $X$ is the "true" value to be estimated, $k_i \in 1,2,3,\ldots$ is a discrete noise variable, and $n_{ij} \in [0, +\infty)$ is a continuous noise variable. $k_i$ and $n_{ij}$ are i.i.d., and are independent of each other.  *Only* $\{x_i\}$ are observed.  Estimate $X$.

(Physical intuition: A ball is thrown back and forth between two actors $k_i$ times.  Each throw adds a random delay, $n_{ij}$.  Knowing only the set of *total* times for the games of catch, $\{x_i\}$, recover the one-way travel time, $X$.)

(The small-sample constraint is for practical reasons: each measurement is fairly expensive.)

I would prefer an answer making as few assumptions about underlying distributions as possible, but we do know a little bit about them.  There is a value known in advance, $\kappa$, such that *most* of the $k_i$ will be equal to $\kappa$, *most* of the exceptions will be equal to $\kappa+1$, and so on.  When $\kappa > 1$, it is theoretically possible for $k_i$ to be *less* than $\kappa$, but it should almost never happen.  The $n_{ij}$ are less well characterized: the best guess I have for their distribution is "some sort of heavy-tailed pseudo-exponential thing," and prior research suggests that they can get really, really messy, with multiple strong modes and so on.  The expectation value for $n$ is on the order of $X/10$, but individual values larger than $20X$ *will* happen.  Worse, estimates of the distribution of $n$ done in one locality are worse than useless in another locality.  (This is a field study, with global scope.)  However, it is *sometimes* possible to make independent field estimations of $n$ (using another method), whereas $k$ can only be directly observed under lab conditions.  (I'm sorry, I can't be more specific about what we are actually measuring.)

I know basic linear regression, and a little bit about mixed models, but the way the *number* of continuous noises is itself random puts it beyond my knowledge.

Comment: I think the index for summation should start from $j=1$. Comment

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Er, yes. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the problem unambiguously, so I will write down the assumptions with some new assumptions amended (independence and such, come with critique/better assumptions). We have
$$
   x_i = 2k_i X + \sum_{j=1}^{2k_i} n_{ij}  ,\qquad i=1, \dotsc N
$$
where $x_i$ is the observed data, $X$ is the unknown quantity to be estimated, 
$k_1, k_N$ are observed independent random variables with common probability function $p(k), k=1,2,3,\dotsc$, $n_{ij}>0$ are unobserved independent random variables with common density function $f(n)$, also independent of the $k_i$'s.

You want a nonparametric solution, without assumptions on the functions $p(k), f(n)$. One simple solution is the method of moments.

Calculate the expectation of $x_i$:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
  \E x_i = 2 \E k_i \cdot X + 2 \E k_i \cdot \E n
$$
then replace the expectations with corresponding arithmetic means, and solve for $X$, which gives as estimator:
$$\hat{X} = \frac{\bar{x}}{2\bar{k}} -\bar{n}
$$
I will come back to this question and try to find some better solution. One obvious problem with this method of moments estimator is that it can give negative estimated values.

Comment: Yes, each random variable may be assumed independent of all the others. However, neither k nor n are observed.  The only available data is $\{x_i\}$.   This unfortunately means I do not see how to apply your estimator.

Comment: @zwol - So there are two unknowns for every known?

Comment: Not even $k$ is observed? Yes, then my solution do not work.  For that situation, you cannot really expect a nonparametric solution---too little is known.  Probably some bayesian solution. Do you have good prior guesses on $k$?  Do you have good prior info on the probable size of $n$? Without that it might be difficult.

Comment: @EngrStudent It's even worse than that: there are $k+1$ unknowns for every observation, and the value of $k$ can be different for each observation! :-(

Comment: That means that we do need some prior information, without that you are doomed ... Can you design some extra experiment to get information on $k$?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen There's reasonably good *a priori* grounds to think that $k$ has very high probability of being 2, and that $n$ are drawn from some kind of heavy-tailed exponential-family distribution, but I would hesitate to say any more than that.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen For tedious technical reasons, direct measurement of $k$ is flat-out impossible.  Characterizing $n$ in a pilot experiment *might* be practical, but this is a field study with global scope, and I am worried that any calibration I do will be invalidated when the experiment is moved out of my local environment.  (I am sorry I can't be more specific about exactly what we are measuring.)

Comment: With so little information I would go for a Bayesian solution, and then doing it with various priors to see the influence from the priors. Will se if I get time to write out something!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I've added what was said here plus a little more to the statement of the question.  I haven't worked with Bayesian methods in the past, and am curious to know what you come up with.  Thanks for your help so far.